# What to do with the access token I get from google oauth2.0

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I was following a video tutorial from youtube where they have used `react-google-login` package to get add google login functionality and get `name`, `googleId`, `imageUrl`. Now I found the package is discontinued. So I am trying to use `@react-oauth/google` my code is below:

```
import {useGoogleLogin} from '@react-oauth/google'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"
import  {FcGoogle}  from "react-icons/fc"
import shareVideo from "../assets/share.mp4"
import logo from "../assets/logowhite.png"
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
//import { isButtonElement } from "react-router-dom/dist/dom"



export default function Login(){

    const login = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: (tokenResponse) =>{
        console.log(tokenResponse)
        }
      })
    return (
        <>
        <div className= "flex justify-start item-center flex-col h-screen">
            <div className="relative w-full h-full">
                <video 
                src={shareVideo}
                type="video/mp4"
                loop
                controls={false}
                muted
                autoPlay
                className="w-full h-full object-cover"
                />
                <div className="absolute flex justify-center items-center top-0 right-0 left-0 bottom-0 bg-blackOverlay">
                    <div className="p-5">
                    <img src={logo} width="130px" alt="logo" className="logo-image"/>
                        <div ce="shadow-2xl">
                        <button 
                        type="button"
                        className="bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none"
                        onClick={()=>login()}
                        //disabled={}
                        >
                            <FcGoogle className="mr-4"/>
                            Sign in with Google
                            </button>
                        
                                {/* <button
                                type="button"
                                className="bg-mainColor flex justify-center items-center p-3 rounded-lg cursor-pointer outline-none"
                                onClick={() => login()}
                                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
                                >
                                    <FcGoogle className="mr-4"/>
                                    Sign inlassNam with Google
                                </button> */}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>   
    )
}
```

In Response I am getting below object:

```
{
    "access_token": "ya29.a0Ad52N386QefhDxf2ufdqQbH6z11NiIfQ0vxUar9VrBBkt-y78wGvurY36MLU-2qpxMEcfaZPetJIwCBfefhLC4_C_ZAeLABhTFxbhxvBCDMkvYN8TKOr4715-85aOO1rXIQ6Sk_q9AfVrVjIkKwS0qNn07Mm2VvQOQaCgYKAUgSARMSFQHGX2MihFifuKvvN4ce-5cwezv4pw0169",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "scope": "email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
    "authuser": "3",
    "prompt": "consent"
}
```

Now I don't know what to do with this to get my required information `name`, `googleId`, `imageUrl`.